Plotly chart not displayed in jupyter notebook
I want to generate and display plotly charts in a jupyter notebook but for reasons I don't understand, its not working. Here's my simple code:
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objects as go

pyo.init_notebook_mode()

summary = {'text/csv': 2, 'application/json': 1}
summary = {'Apples': 30, 'Bananas': 45, 'Cherries': 25}

mimetypes = list(summary.keys())
counts = list(summary.values())

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=mimetypes, y=counts))

fig.update_layout(
    title='Fruit Count',
    xaxis_title='Fruit',
    yaxis_title='Count'
)

# Show plot
fig.show()

When I execute the cell it displays blank output:

Can anyone suggest why its not displaying anything?
Extra info:

I'm using python 3.12

The packages I installed (from requirements.txt):


google-api-python-client
google-auth-httplib2
google-auth-oauthlib
jupyter
plotly
pandas

(google packages are needed for something else, I only mention here for completeness)

List of all installed packages is:

anyio==4.4.0
argon2-cffi==23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
arrow==1.3.0
asttokens==2.4.1
async-lru==2.0.4
attrs==23.2.0
Babel==2.15.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
bleach==6.1.0
cachetools==5.3.3
certifi==2024.7.4
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
comm==0.2.2
debugpy==1.8.2
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
executing==2.0.1
fastjsonschema==2.20.0
fqdn==1.5.1
google-api-core==2.19.1
google-api-python-client==2.137.0
google-auth==2.32.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.2.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.2.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.63.2
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.5
httplib2==0.22.0
httpx==0.27.0
idna==3.7
ipykernel==6.29.5
ipython==8.26.0
ipywidgets==8.1.3
isoduration==20.11.0
jedi==0.19.1
Jinja2==3.1.4
json5==0.9.25
jsonpointer==3.0.0
jsonschema==4.23.0
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-console==6.6.3
jupyter-events==0.10.0
jupyter-lsp==2.2.5
jupyter_client==8.6.2
jupyter_core==5.7.2
jupyter_server==2.14.1
jupyter_server_terminals==0.5.3
jupyterlab==4.2.3
jupyterlab_pygments==0.3.0
jupyterlab_server==2.27.2
jupyterlab_widgets==3.0.11
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
matplotlib-inline==0.1.7
mistune==3.0.2
nbclient==0.10.0
nbconvert==7.16.4
nbformat==5.10.4
nest-asyncio==1.6.0
notebook==7.2.1
notebook_shim==0.2.4
numpy==2.0.0
oauthlib==3.2.2
overrides==7.7.0
packaging==24.1
pandas==2.2.2
pandocfilters==1.5.1
parso==0.8.4
pexpect==4.9.0
platformdirs==4.2.2
plotly==5.22.0
prometheus_client==0.20.0
prompt_toolkit==3.0.47
proto-plus==1.24.0
protobuf==5.27.2
psutil==6.0.0
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
pyasn1==0.6.0
pyasn1_modules==0.4.0
pycparser==2.22
Pygments==2.18.0
pyparsing==3.1.2
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-json-logger==2.0.7
pytz==2024.1
PyYAML==6.0.1
pyzmq==26.0.3
qtconsole==5.5.2
QtPy==2.4.1
referencing==0.35.1
requests==2.32.3
requests-oauthlib==2.0.0
rfc3339-validator==0.1.4
rfc3986-validator==0.1.1
rpds-py==0.19.0
rsa==4.9
Send2Trash==1.8.3
setuptools==70.3.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.1
soupsieve==2.5
stack-data==0.6.3
tenacity==8.5.0
terminado==0.18.1
tinycss2==1.3.0
tornado==6.4.1
traitlets==5.14.3
types-python-dateutil==2.9.0.20240316
tzdata==2024.1
uri-template==1.3.0
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==2.2.2
wcwidth==0.2.13
webcolors==24.6.0
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.8.0
widgetsnbextension==4.0.11



Disable pyo.init_notebook_mode()? It may be improved by modifying fig.show('notebook') according to the explanation in the reference.

Thanks. Tried both of those suggestions but still seeing the same behaviour.

Did you try running the cell a few times? Was it working prior to this with more typical plotly use? Did you try more current code using online too? Does that work? On the horizon is the issue that you look to be using old notebook interface with very current Python. (Is it at least NbClassic?) Not ready to point to that yet but it is somewhat concerning.

Thx Wayne. Yes, have tried running the cell many times. Haven't had any plotly charts rendering here yet. Not sure what NvClassic refers to, I'm using jupyterlab. You may be onto something regarding use of python 3.12, I'll try downgrading to 3.11 and see if it helps.

downgrading to python3.11 solved it. I've posted an answer with all the details.

I seem to have fixed this by downgrading to python 3.11. These are the steps I took:

switched to using python 3.11 by changing the docker image that I'm running upon (I am using Visual StudioCode devcontainers).
removed existing virtualenv
created a new virtualenv using python 3.11 and installed the same dependencies from requirements.txt

I then open up my jupyter notebook. Interestingly I didn't have to re-run any cells, the chart was already present within the notebook. This means it was always in the notebook when using python 3.12, it just wasn't being displayed properly.

In case anyone is interested here are the versions of dependencies that have been installed:
anyio==4.4.0
argon2-cffi==23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
arrow==1.3.0
asttokens==2.4.1
async-lru==2.0.4
attrs==23.2.0
Babel==2.15.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
bleach==6.1.0
cachetools==5.3.3
certifi==2024.7.4
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
comm==0.2.2
debugpy==1.8.2
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
executing==2.0.1
fastjsonschema==2.20.0
fqdn==1.5.1
google-api-core==2.19.1
google-api-python-client==2.137.0
google-auth==2.32.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.2.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.2.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.63.2
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==1.0.5
httplib2==0.22.0
httpx==0.27.0
idna==3.7
ipykernel==6.29.5
ipython==8.26.0
ipywidgets==8.1.3
isoduration==20.11.0
jedi==0.19.1
Jinja2==3.1.4
json5==0.9.25
jsonpointer==3.0.0
jsonschema==4.23.0
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-console==6.6.3
jupyter-events==0.10.0
jupyter-lsp==2.2.5
jupyter_client==8.6.2
jupyter_core==5.7.2
jupyter_server==2.14.2
jupyter_server_terminals==0.5.3
jupyterlab==4.2.3
jupyterlab_pygments==0.3.0
jupyterlab_server==2.27.2
jupyterlab_widgets==3.0.11
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
matplotlib-inline==0.1.7
mistune==3.0.2
nbclient==0.10.0
nbconvert==7.16.4
nbformat==5.10.4
nest-asyncio==1.6.0
notebook==7.2.1
notebook_shim==0.2.4
numpy==2.0.0
oauthlib==3.2.2
overrides==7.7.0
packaging==24.1
pandas==2.2.2
pandocfilters==1.5.1
parso==0.8.4
pexpect==4.9.0
platformdirs==4.2.2
plotly==5.22.0
polars==1.1.0
prometheus_client==0.20.0
prompt_toolkit==3.0.47
proto-plus==1.24.0
protobuf==5.27.2
psutil==6.0.0
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
pyasn1==0.6.0
pyasn1_modules==0.4.0
pycparser==2.22
Pygments==2.18.0
pyparsing==3.1.2
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
python-json-logger==2.0.7
pytz==2024.1
PyYAML==6.0.1
pyzmq==26.0.3
qtconsole==5.5.2
QtPy==2.4.1
referencing==0.35.1
requests==2.32.3
requests-oauthlib==2.0.0
rfc3339-validator==0.1.4
rfc3986-validator==0.1.1
rpds-py==0.19.0
rsa==4.9
Send2Trash==1.8.3
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.1
soupsieve==2.5
stack-data==0.6.3
tenacity==8.5.0
terminado==0.18.1
tinycss2==1.3.0
tornado==6.4.1
traitlets==5.14.3
types-python-dateutil==2.9.0.20240316
typing_extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.1
uri-template==1.3.0
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==2.2.2
wcwidth==0.2.13
webcolors==24.6.0
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.8.0
widgetsnbextension==4.0.1

I wrote the dependency list of each to text files and compared them, here's what it came back with:
> diff 3.11.txt 3.12.txt 
49c49
< jupyter_server==2.14.2
---
> jupyter_server==2.14.1
74d73
> setuptools==70.3.0
112d111
< typing_extensions==4.12.2
121a121
> 

Seems to me the only significant difference is the python version.
